# profiled Relationship matrix in html reports in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

How can i include a profiled Relationship matrix in html reports in Enterprise Architect.
I have a link on each diagram which points to a profiled relationship matrix.
I tried to generate a html report for my project. But all these relation matrix links are disabled.

Comment: Which version of EA do you use?

Answer (score 0):

A relationship matrix can't be directly included in an HTML generation and there's no way to script running it or exporting it to an image file. But you can include it in an RTF document, so here's a sort of workaround based on RTF templates and virtual documents.

1. Create an RTF template which outputs the relationship matrix image. You might want to include the package name and the current date and time as well.
2. For each package you want a matrix report for, create a «model document» and add the package to it. Please note that if you've defined multiple relationship matrices for a package, you can't choose which one to report - EA will just pick one.
3. For each «model document», create an Artifact and draw a «trace» from the «model document» to the Artifact.
4. Move the Artifacts to a package which is included in the HTML generation. You don't have to place them in any diagrams if you don't want to, but they must reside inside the hierarchy for which HTML is generated.

The «model document»:s should be in a separate package which is not included in the HTML generation. Name them according to the scheme "pkgname - matrixname" or similar.

The Artifacts should be given names which make sense within the generated HTML - call them "Requirement Matrix: pkgname" or similar.

Now, before you run your HTML generation, you must run the matrix reports individually and manually by right-clicking the Artifact in the same diagram as the «model document» and selecting "Create Document to Artifact" (so it's a good idea to include the date and time in the template). Then generate your HTML as usual.

This will output the matrix images into the HTML. You'll have to click the document to see the image and as noted you'll have to run the matrix reports manually, but the result will be there.

You could do something similar by placing hyperlinks to image files in your diagrams and then output the different matrices to these image files. I prefer the Artifact method, because it keeps everything inside EA (no broken links) and it gives you the option of including the report date and time and more stuff if you want it.